# Structuring DIV layouts on a site built with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

We've just purchased a stock theme, `Blockshop`, for our forthcoming Woocommerce site. The team here are comfortable with HTML and CSS, and we have a loose understanding of the purpose of PHP, but no real knowledge of applying or altering it.

On our category page, there is a DIV that holds two filters - one product filter and one sort by filter - and we'd like it to be repositioned underneath the category description, to make the page easier to follow.

Here is an example of a populated category page: https://onemanmusic.co.uk/yamaha-clp-clavinova/ - you'll see from the page source that the DIV in question is "shop-header-wrapper visible" - ideally we'd like this to display beneath the `woocommerce-products-header` DIV if at all possible, but we're all clueless as to where to locate the relevant HTML within the theme files.

I have a loose understanding that the PHP is calling the filter function to appear, but I've no idea how to tell it to show in the desired place.

I've located the script in question, and I'm able to alter it and remove it from display, but I can't seem to reposition it:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'blockshop_shop_archive_header' ) ) :
    /**
     * Header area for Shop Archive
     */
    function blockshop_shop_archive_header() {
        if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) :
            $categories = get_terms(
                'product_cat',
                array(
                    'hide_empty' => 0,
                    'parent'     => 0,
                )
            );
            if ( woocommerce_get_loop_display_mode() === 'subcategories' || woocommerce_get_loop_display_mode() === 'both' ) {
                $subcategories = $categories;
            }

            $current_cat = 0;
            if ( is_product_category() ) {
                global $wp_query;
                $current_cat    = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                $current_cat_id = isset( $current_cat->term_id ) ? $current_cat->term_id : 0;
                if ( 0 !== $current_cat_id ) {
                    $subcategories = get_terms(
                        'product_cat',
                        array(
                            'hide_empty' => 0,
                            'parent'     => $current_cat_id,
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            ?>
        <div class="shop-header-wrapper">
            <div class="shop-header-block">
                <div class="filter">
                    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'shop-filters-widgets' ) ) : ?>
                        <span class="toggle-filter">
                            <i class="icon-filter"></i><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Filter', 'block-shop' ); ?></span>
                        </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <?php if ( 'yes' === BlockShop_Opt::get_option( 'category_menu' ) ) : ?>
                <div class="shop-categories">
                    <ul class="shop-list">
                    <?php
                    $shop_page_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
                    if ( ! empty( $shop_page_url ) ) :
                        ?>
                        <li class="cat-item 
                        <?php
                        if ( is_shop() ) {
                            echo 'current-cat';}
                        ?>
                        ">
                            <?php
                            if ( is_shop() ) {
                                echo '<h1>';}
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $shop_page_url ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ); ?></a>
                            <span class="count"><?php echo esc_html( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ); ?></span>
                            <?php
                            if ( is_shop() ) {
                                echo '</h1>';}
                            ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                    endif;
                    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) :
                        foreach ( $categories as $cat ) :
                            if ( 0 === $cat->count ) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            ?>
                            <li class="cat-item 
                            <?php
                            if ( isset( $current_cat_id ) && $current_cat_id === $cat->term_id ) {
                                echo 'current-cat';}
                            ?>
                            ">
                                <?php
                                if ( isset( $current_cat_id ) && $current_cat_id === $cat->term_id ) {
                                    echo '<h1>';}
                                ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $cat->slug, 'product_cat' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $cat->name ); ?></a>
                                <span class="count"><?php echo esc_attr( $cat->count ); ?></span>
                                <?php
                                if ( isset( $current_cat_id ) && $current_cat_id === $cat->term_id ) {
                                    echo '</h1>';}
                                ?>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                        endforeach;
                    endif;
                    ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters' ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="sort-products">
                        <?php do_action( 'blockshop_woocommerce_catalog_ordering' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
                <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'shop-filters-widgets' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="expanded-filter">
                <div class="woocommerce-widgets-wrapper">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'shop-filters-widgets' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
            <?php
        endif;
    }
endif;
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'blockshop_shop_archive_header', 10 );
```

I'd anticipated to simply be able to cut and paste the code into the right place, but clearly this isn't the layout in question.

Apologies in advance if this is embarrassingly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify this you need to alter the rendering order, from your code

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'blockshop_shop_archive_header', 10 );`

This block of code sets the priority to 10, so in order to make this appear after `woocommerce-products-header` you need to assign a greater priority to `blockshop_shop_archive_header`.

Please see excerpt from the docs

`add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )`

> $priority
>
> (int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
>
> Default value: 10

The order of execution is determined by the `$priority`, so in your instance if you assign a priority greater than `woocommerce-products-header` to `blockshop_shop_archive_header` it should appear after it.

Please see the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) for more info

Comment: thanks for your fast response. I've been poring over it so I didn't just come back cap in hand for a spoonfed solution (thanks for the link also.)

Pardon my ignorance, but is this something I'll need to do inside the same page of code? Is it a case of adding a string or altering one that is already there?

Thanks

Comment: You need to alter something, can you look for the file containing `woocommerce-products-header` (since you want the filter to be positioned after this), you need to know where the action for that div is added.

Comment: Just to recap the `$priority` of `blockshop_shop_archive_header` needs to be greater than that of `woocommerce-products-header` for it to come after. This is why you should find its file

Comment: I'm starting to appreciate the logic of what you're saying - I can't seem to determine where the header is shown (it must be there somewhere), so I'm at a loss still before I even battle with the add_Action function! 

It might be something I have to outsource - thanks for your assistance thus far though.

Comment: @DavidCooper if you can't find it, maybe you can try increasing the priority and see if `blockshop_shop_archive_header` changes position. Its currently set at 10 so you can try multiples of 10 ie 20, 30, 40 etc. Example  replace the value in the code above to `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'blockshop_shop_archive_header', 20 );` etc.

Comment: thanks for sticking with this! I did try but still no joy with any multiples up to 60. I'm wondering whether or not theres an HTML option, if I can physically restructure the snippet and disable the add_action. It's a very slick theme but it's structure is somewhat obfusive

Answer (score 0):

I applied the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'blockshop_shop_archive_header', 10 );
```

...which has placed the block below the category description, as desired. Thank you for your help - it gave me the right direction!